# android appium click “content-desc” attribute not working

Tags: android, python, appium

The 'content-desc' is 'Submit ', yet click() doesn't appear to work? Any suggestions would be appreciated? I've also tried the tap TouchAction?

(using Python) I'm getting an '... element could not be located on the page .. ' error when trying to click the submit button.

I've tried by accessiblity id and xpath as follows:

driver.find_element_by_accessibility_id("Submit ").click()
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//android.view.View/android.widget.Button[@content-desc='Submit ']").click()

also tried the following tap touchaction:

```
    elem = driver.find_element_by_accessibility_id("Submit ")
    action = TouchAction(driver)
    action.tap(elem).perform()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try With findElement by name .

Answer (score 0):

use the below as xpath:

```
//*[@class = 'android.widget.Button' and @content-desc ='Submit']
```

hope this helps and let me know what happens.

Answer (score 0):

It almost looks like you are entering in white space at the end of the content-desc tag. I would recommend using the following xpath instead.

`//android.view.View/android.widget.Button[contains(@content-desc,'Submit')]`.

This way if the white space changes then your test doesn't fail later

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
els = self.driver.find_element_by_android_uiautomator('new UiSelector().description(Submit)')
```